# Using Snowflake & Apache Airflow, how can I change DATABASE or SCHEMA for a connection using SqlSensor?

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm new to Snowflake (and using it in Apache Airflow).  I'm attempting to use the SqlSensor with it.

I've found that the Snowflake driver doesn't allow multi-statement SQL.  The SnowflakeOperator appears to have worked around this by splitting on ; and executing the statements one at a time.

Snowflake is a valid connection type for SqlOperator.  But, I haven't noticed an SqlSensor specifically for Snowflake.  The SqlOperator doesn't split commands the way the SnowflakeOperator does. Therefore it seems like each query to use for sensing must be established on the right database and schema from the get go, i.e. no USE DATABASE type commands - otherwise it is multi-statement and the sensor fails.

Do I need to establish a separate airflow connection for each Schema and Database I might choose to sense?  Or is there another way to specify the DATABASE, SCHEMA, etc at runtime using the SqlSensor?

Comment: I don't know SqlSensor, but can you just fully qualify your database/schema in your object references?  This would allow you to connect to any database/schema and still query any other database/schema.

Comment: What do you mean by 'object references', I'm not familar with the term. Do you mean the connection itself (like in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html)?

Comment: Oh, nvm, I think you mean in the sql query itself.  I'll give that a try. :facepalm:

Comment: Please explain your use case. Sensor meant by desgin to run a single SELECT. Why would you need to split query in sensor? Do you use it with USE DATBASE X; SELECT....?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SqlSensor` is designed to accept single query.
I assume that you are trying to run queries like:

```sql
USE DATABASE my_database;
USE SCHEMA my_schema;
SELECT ...
```

Which doesn't work.

---

**Update:**

You can simply use `hook_params`:

```
from airflow.providers.common.sql.sensors.sql import SqlSensor
SqlSensor(
    task_id='my_task',
    conn_id='snowflake_conn',
    sql="SELECT 1",
    hook_params={
        'database': 'my_database',
        'schema': 'my_schema',
    },
)
```

That will work for any version of [apache-airflow-providers-common-sql](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-common-sql)

---

In case your Airflow version is old (doesn't support the common.sql provider):

You can still solve your problem with one of the following:

1. Define another Snowflake connection that you will not need to change its properties in the query thus you will run only a single SELECT statement.
2. create a custom `SnowflakeSensor`.

I didn't test it but the general idea is something like

```py
from airflow.sensors.sql import SqlSensor
from airflow.providers.snowflake.hooks.snowflake import SnowflakeHook

class SnowflakeSensor(SqlSensor):
    def __init__(
        self, **kwargs
    ):
        self.account = kwargs.pop("account", None)
        self.warehouse = kwargs.pop("warehouse", None)
        self.database = kwargs.pop("database", None)
        self.region = kwargs.pop("region", None)
        self.role = kwargs.pop("role", None)
        self.schema = kwargs.pop("schema", None)
        self.authenticator = kwargs.pop("authenticator", None)
        self.session_parameters = kwargs.pop("session_parameters", None)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def _get_hook(self):
        return SnowflakeHook(
            snowflake_conn_id=self.conn_id,
            warehouse=self.warehouse,
            database=self.database,
            role=self.role,
            schema=self.schema,
            authenticator=self.authenticator,
            session_parameters=self.session_parameters,
        )
```

What this code does is everything that `SqlSensor` does with the difference that it accept also Snowflake specific parameters by overwriting the `_get_hook` function.

Comment: Thank you! You correctly intuited my error and this solution looks great.

Comment: Small edit suggestion and/or nit for someone picking this up.  SqlSensor expects the argument conn_id and the SnowflakeHook expects snowflake_conn_id.  So, call the SnowflakeSensor with the arg, 'conn_id' and adapt the argument for SnowflakeHook so that what you assign to snowflake_conn_id would be self.conn_id.

Comment: @russellpierce edited. thanks